# How to write a nested Excel formula to SQL

Tags: sql, excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have an Excel formula with nested "IF" and want to write it in an  SQL.

```
IF(K2<=50000,"-",IF(F2<=50000,IF(MIN(H2,HI2)<=30%,"Riesgo Medio","-"),IF(F2<100000,IF(MIN(H2,I2)<=30%,"Riesgo Medio",IF(MIN(H2,I2)>=65%,"Riesgo bajo","kyc")),IF(MIN(H2,I2)<=30%,"Riesgo alto",IF(MIN(H2,I2)>=65%,"Riesgo bajo","Riesgo Medio")))))
```

Comment: Start by changing the `IF` to `CASE WHEN / ELSE` and the `MIN` to `CASE WHEN x < y THEN x ELSE Y` and post your efforts after that.

Comment: i think you have a typo there. you wrote (H2,HI2). did you mean (H2,I2)?